# Dozer mapping class A -> Class B

Tags: dozer

I have a confusion that I am mapping 2 objects via Dozer mapping. So one class A has typeCode and another class B has typeCode(same spelling) and isCashFund
I have written custom converter for typeCode => isCashfund but will it now not populate the typeCode of class B as now it is not one to one mapping.

```
<mapping>
<class-a>TsmfFund</class-a>
<class-b>Fund</class-b>
<field type="one-way">
<a>priceTypeSet.description</a>
<b>priceTypeSetDescription</b>
</field>
<field>
<a>currencyCode</a>
<b>currency</b>
</field>
<field type="one-way" custom-converter="FundTypeConverter">
        <a>typeCode</a>
        <b>cashFund</b>
    </field>
</mapping>
```

Comment: Comment section is for comments not for additional details. Edit your question.

Comment: Have you tried to explicitly add `typeCode` to `typeCode` mapping?

Comment: I haven't tried it but should we do it?

Comment: Do you want to solve your problem?

Comment: I wanted to know the root cause why it would do that ,  not just solve the problem and may be to learn something more.

Comment: Well it seems pretty obvious. If field is already mapped to some field why it should be mapped to another field.

Comment: I has been mapped via custom converter and the implicit mapping is via field name to field name. Will the custom converter override that mapping?

Comment: You have provided mapping for the field. Why dozer should map it again?